# JSXGraph - Persistency Problem : Drawing more than one function

Tags: jsxgraph

I want to draw multiple-graphs inside for loop using JSXGraph code. Everthing seems ok, working but when I click a point or a tangent line, they all disappears since they under for loop. What I understood is that I need to put them inside a paint function (and update somewhere) like in Java, but I could not success to find it. What is the proper way to draw persistence multiple graphs using for loop? Thanks.
This is my code :

```js
// functions and derivatives 
const board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jxgbox', {
  boundingbox: [-10, 10, 10, -10],
  axis: true
});

// Macro function plotter
function addCurve(board, func, atts) {
  var f = board.create('functiongraph', [func], atts);
  return f;
}

// Simplified plotting of function
function plot(func, atts) {
  if (atts == null) {
    return addCurve(board, func, {
      strokecolor: 'green',
      strokewidth: 2
    });
  } else {
    return addCurve(board, func, atts);
  }
}
    
// function of x
function f(x) {
  return Math.pow(x,2);
}

//draw f
c = plot(f);
  
//define derivative function, let command provide not to write "var" keyword
// in front of each variables

let ms=[],
  i=0,
  m=0,
  co=[],
  funcs=[],
  points=[];

for(i=0; i<11; i++) {
  m=(f(i+1)-f(i-1))/(i+1-i+1);
  co[i]=f(i)-m*i;    
  ms[i]=m;
  console.log("y="+ms[i]+"x+("+co[i]+")");
  
  // Create a function graph for each derivative function df(x) = ms[i]*x+co[i]
  funcs[i] = board.create('functiongraph',
    [function(x){ return ms[i]*x+co[i];}, -10, 10]
  );
  
  // Create a constrained point using anonymous function
    points[i] = board.create('point', [i, function () { return ms[i]; }]);  
}

console.log("aha"+c);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example code is completely correct beside a few subleties regarding `let` and `var`. The trick is to define `i` and `m` with `let` in the for-loop block that creates the derivative function graphs, but to define the arrays containing the slopes (`ms`) and constant values (`co`) with `var`. The latter makes the arrays persisent and the former is equivalent to define the functions "by hand" like

```
funcs[0] = board.create('functiongraph', [
    function(x){ return ms[0] * x + co[0]; }, -10, 10]
);
funcs[1] = board.create('functiongraph', [
    function(x){ return ms[1] * x + co[1]; }, -10, 10]
);
...
```

Here is the code for the loop:

```
var c = plot(f);

var ms=[],
  co=[],
  funcs=[],
  points=[];

for (let i=0; i<11; i++) {
  let m = (f(i+1)-f(i-1)) / (i+1-i+1);
  co[i] = f(i) - m * i;    
  ms[i] = m;
  console.log("y=" + ms[i] + "x+(" + co[i] + ")");

  // Create a function graph for each derivative function df(x) = ms[i]*x+co[i]
  funcs[i] = board.create('functiongraph',
    [function(x){ return ms[i] * x + co[i]; }, -10, 10]
  );

  // Create a constrained point using anonymous function
  points[i] = board.create('point', [i, function () { return ms[i]; }]);  
}
```

See it live at https://jsfiddle.net/sp2ntf8v/

Comment: Ok! I did not know that the difference between let and var keywords' characteristics. Thanks :).